# Copy element with its properties in mootools

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

The Following is the code I am using in Mootools,

```
var company_name = $('company_name-wrapper').clone();
company_name.inject($('wmd-button-bar'));
```

The HTML is as follows,

```
<div id="company_name-wrapper" class="form-wrapper" style='float:left;'>
   <div id="company_name-label" class="form-label">
       <label for="company_name" class="required">
          Company
       </label>
   </div>
   <div id="company_name-element" class="form-element">
      <input type="text" name="company_name[]" id="company_name" value="">
   </div>
</div>

..............
..............

<div id='wmd-button-bar'></div>
```

The **Output** I am getting after executing the code is,

```
<div id='wmd-button-bar'>
 <div class="form-wrapper">
   <div class="form-label">
       <label for="company_name" class="required">
          Company
       </label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-element">
      <input type="text" name="company_name[]" id="company_name" value="">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The Id's or the style of any elements is not getting cloned.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated, 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mootools avoids copying ID's to avoid getting double ID's, but you can override that using `.clone([contents, keepid])` *keepid* function [paramenters](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3aclone).

So try using: `var company_name = $('company_name-wrapper').clone(true, true);`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HtaEv/)

Notice that doing so you will have duplicate ID's and that is **invalid HTML**, it will give you problems when you try to refer to different elements with the same ID.